# Cannot use the entry API to mutate a HashMap using a reference as the key inside of a function

Tags: rust, hashmap, borrow-checker

I'm trying to get a handle to an element in a mutable `HashMap` reference where the keys are `&str`.

In the example below, I'm trying to get value `dict[key]` so I can mutate it. How do I do this?

I've tried:

- `dict.entry(key)`: lifetime mismatch
- `dict.entry(&String::from(key))`: borrowed value does not live long enough

e.g. this:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn do_thing(key: &str, dict: &mut HashMap<&str, u32>) -> u32 {
    let num = dict.entry(&String::from(key)).or_insert(0);
    *num += 1;
    return 42;
}
```

Errors out with:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
 --> src/lib.rs:4:27
  |
3 | fn do_thing(key: &str, dict: &mut HashMap<&str, u32>) -> u32 {
  |                                           - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
4 |     let num = dict.entry(&String::from(key)).or_insert(0);
  |               ------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-             - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
  |               |           |
  |               |           creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
  |               argument requires that borrow lasts for `'1`
```

Comment: @Shepmaster Nice edit -- question is clearer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Link the lifetime of the `key` argument to the lifetime of the keys in the `HashMap`:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn do_thing<'a>(key: &'a str, dict: &mut HashMap<&'a str, u32>) -> u32 {
    *dict.entry(key).or_insert(0) += 1;
    42
}
```

---

> `dict.entry(key)`

The error message for this version helps understand the problem:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn do_thing(key: &str, dict: &mut HashMap<&str, u32>) -> u32 {
    *dict.entry(key).or_insert(0) += 1;
    42
}
```

```
error[E0623]: lifetime mismatch
 --> src/lib.rs:4:17
  |
3 | fn do_thing(key: &str, dict: &mut HashMap<&str, u32>) -> u32 {
  |                  ----                     ----
  |                  |
  |                  these two types are declared with different lifetimes...
4 |     *dict.entry(key).or_insert(0) += 1;
  |                 ^^^ ...but data from `key` flows into `dict` here
```

Specifically, `entry` will store `key` in the `HashMap`, but the value referenced by `key` might become invalid **before** the `HashMap` does. If that happened, the `HashMap` would contain a dangling reference, pointing to invalid memory. That's exactly what Rust's borrow checker prevents.

See also:

- [When is it required to use lifetimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41654864/155423)
- [Why are explicit lifetimes needed in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31609137/155423)

> `dict.entry(&String::from(key))`

This can never work here, for much the same reason.

See also:

- [Return local String as a slice (&str)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29428227/155423)