# Why does borrow checker need life time tags for output when the inputs are very clear?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker, borrowing

Why does the borrow checker gets confused about the lifetimes in the below code

```
fn main() {
    let ss = "abc"; // lets say 'a scope
    let tt = "def"; // lets say 'b scope
    let result = func(ss, tt);
}    

fn func(s: &str, t: &str) -> &str {
    t
}
```

```
| fn func(s: &str, t: &str) -> &str {
|                              ^ expected lifetime parameter
|
= help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but the signature does not say whether it is borrowed from `s` or `t`
```

Why does it even matter what is going out in this code? Am I missing something very important edge case?

but when I annotate them with life time tags it works.

```
fn func<'a>(s: &'a str, t: &'a str) -> &'a str {
    t
}
```

I read that each variable binding (let) creates an Implicit scope, then how come 2 input variables have same scope. Correct me If I'm worng. In the function call 'func' stack, "s" will be pushed first and then "t", So "s" and "t" have different lifetimes. First "t" is dropped and then "s".

Comment: You have three different lifetimes `'a`, `'b` and `'c` (for the output). How should the compiler know which one depends on which? :/ So this is not *very clear* for the compiler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are explicit lifetimes needed in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31609137/why-are-explicit-lifetimes-needed-in-rust)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven’t told the compiler whether the return value may borrow from `s`, from `t`, from both, or from neither:

```rs
fn from_s<'a, 'b>(s: &'a str, t: &'b str) -> &'a str {
    // can be abbreviated: fn from_s<'a>(s: &'a str, t: &str) -> &'a str
    s
}

fn from_t<'a, 'b>(s: &'a str, t: &'b str) -> &'b str {
    // can be abbreviated: fn from_t<'a>(s: &str, t: &'a str) -> &'a str
    t
}

fn from_both<'a>(s: &'a str, t: &'a str) -> &'a str {
    if s < t {
        s
    } else {
        t
    }
}

fn from_neither<'a, 'b>(s: &'a str, t: &'b str) -> &'static str {
    // can be abbreviated: fn func(s: &str, t: &str) -> &'static str
    "foo"
}
```

The compiler can assume the last one isn’t what you wanted if you didn’t write `'static`.  But you still need to disambiguate between the first three.

To see why the difference would matter, consider a caller like

```rs
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("s");
    let r;
    {
        let t = String::from("t");
        r = from_s(&s, &t);
        // t goes out of scope
    }
    println!("{}", r);
}
```

If the compiler allowed you to call `from_t` instead of `from_s`, you’d be printing a string that had already been freed.

Comment: Woudln't the fact that the function returns `t` be enough to know the lifetime?

Comment: @coredump The type of the function is supposed to encapsulate everything there is to know about how it can and can't be called. If you have to peek inside the implementation to see how it can be called, then the implementation becomes part of the public interface; every change to the implementation becomes a potentially backwards-incompatible change. And traits with multiple potential implementations would no longer be possible to specify. Basically, it would be bad.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the question is "why both arguments may have the same lifetime?" The short answer is that the lifetime annotations are not *concrete* values, but rather *bounds* - it states that "this value must live no more/no less then this lifetime".

When you're writing your code as you do in question: `fn func<'a>(s: &'a str, t: &'a str) -> &'a str`, you're saying literally the following:

- there is some lifetime - let's name it `'a`, which can be different on every call site.
- arguments `s` and `t` must both live *no less* then `'a` (for string literals, this is always the case, since they are `'static`, but this may not hold for `&String` coerced to `&str`) - that is, function type is **contra**variant over arguments types (and the lifetime is part of a type).
- return value must live *no more* then `'a` - function type is **co**variant over the return type.

(for more information on variance see the [Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html))

Simplified, this means that both arguments must outlive the return value. This is not always what you want - consider the following case (note that I'm returning `s` now, so that the initialization order doesn't change):

```
fn main() {
    let ss = "abc";
    let mut result = "";
    {
        let tt = "def".to_string();
        result = func(ss, &tt);
    }
    println!("{}", result);
}    

fn func<'a>(s: &'a str, t: &'a str) -> &'a str {
    s
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8c1fefc825b3036340f3b7d045a9eb5a))

This code won't compile, although it is logically correct, since the lifetime annotations don't agree with logic: second argument, `t`, is in no way connected to the return value, and yet it limits its lifetime, according to function annotations. But when we change function to the following:

```
fn func<'a, 'b>(s: &'a str, t: &'b str) -> &'a str {
    s
}
```

...it compiles and return the desired result (although with some warnings), since now the lifetime `'b` isn't connected with `'a` and, in fact, can be removed at all - lifetime elision will do its work well.