# Why lifetime was explicitly declared in the following example?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I was going through some solutions to exercise exercises and couldn't figure out why an explicit lifetime declaration is required?

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct HighScores<'a> {
    scores: &'a [u32],
}

impl<'a> HighScores<'a> {
    pub fn new(scores: &'a [u32]) -> Self {
        HighScores { scores }
    }

    pub fn scores(&self) -> &[u32] {
        self.scores
    }

    pub fn latest(&self) -> Option<u32> {
        self.scores.last().cloned()
    }

    pub fn personal_best(&self) -> Option<u32> {
        self.scores.iter().max().cloned()
    }

    pub fn personal_top_three(&self) -> Vec<u32> {
        let mut res_vec = self.scores.to_vec();

        res_vec.sort_unstable_by(|a, b| a.cmp(b).reverse());
        res_vec.truncate(3);

        res_vec
    }
}
```

[Source](https://exercism.io/tracks/rust/exercises/high-scores/solutions/a29a0cd38bc143349f7b7e32733518c2) [Exercism Exercise](https://exercism.io/my/solutions/7f510ac9f90647a1b70e5c99fa40d5d7)

Comment: Because the slice is just borrowed and not owned (like a `Vec<u32>` would be).

Comment: @Stargateur, it does but I couldn't relate that much for this snippet of code.

Comment: ask about learn a language is too broad read https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html. or ask a more focus question https://stackoverflow.com/a/31625653/7076153 answer you

Comment: @hellow, Just to be clear, since it is a reference which may outlive the struct, we should declare the lifetime explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the [lifetime elision rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html)

Consider following not working `new` fn:

```
pub fn new(scores: &[u32]) -> Self {
    HighScores { scores }
}
error[E0621]: explicit lifetime required in the type of `scores`
```

Same as:

```
pub fn new(scores: &[u32]) -> HighScores<'a> {
    HighScores { scores }
}
```

Returning `Self` is the same as returning the type you're currently implementing (`HighScores<'a>`), now you have one elided lifetime for input `&[u32]` that differs from the explicit lifetime in your return type, which is illegal for your example struct.

It should also be noted that the lifetimes declared in your `impl Header` are not available for lifetime elision for an input of a function.

You can either solve this by setting the lifetime for your input:

```
pub fn new(scores: &'a [u32]) -> Self {
    HighScores { scores }
}
```

Or elide the output lifetime:

```
pub fn new(scores: &[u32]) -> HighScores<'_> {
    HighScores { scores }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Initially, I wasn't explicitly declaring the lifetime for the reference in my struct, but that was silly not doing that as the reference may outlive the struct or vice versa. Correct me if I am wrong.